# Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking without Screen name

Tags: android, google-analytics

Hi I'm implementing the Ecommerce Tracking but when Google Analytics get the data, it put them in:

- Conversions >> Transactions (that what's I want)
- and Compartments >> Screen (that I don't want)

Why it put the Screen data (name...) how not to display that data and only to keep transaction data ?

```
if (code.equals("1")) {
    db.updateDateEnvoie(demandeId);
    Product product =  new Product()
        .setId(id)
        .setName(logement)
        .setCategory(typeForm)
        .setPrice(1)
        .setQuantity(1);
    ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
        .setTransactionId(id)
        .setTransactionAffiliation("...")
        .setTransactionRevenue(1);
    HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
        .addProduct(product)
        .setProductAction(productAction);
    Tracker t = ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker();
    t.setScreenName("transaction");
    t.send(builder.build());
}
```

If I delete this line:

```
t.setScreenName("transaction");
```

I get any data..